# How to acces env variable with dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, environment-variables

I'm stuck with my dockerfile, i'll try to get acces to an env. variable who is declaring in my docker-compose.yml but it tell me that the variable do not exist.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
my-project-dev:
container_name: my-project-frontend
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
volumes:
  - './my-project-frontend:/usr/src/app'
  - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
ports:
  - 15242:80
  # - 49153:49153
environment:
  - ENV=dev
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM node:16.14.2 as builder
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build-${ENV}
```

For debuging i try in my dockerfile to "RUN env", [that's the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54zLN.png)

But, when my container is start and i enter on it and i execute "env" [i see my "ENV" variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7cQ0.png)

Anyone have a solution ?

Comment: The issue may be something else. We can't really help you unless you provide the full recipe.

Comment: What more do you need to help me?

Comment: I dont' know. We have to see.

Comment: we just need the `yml` file and the recipe. We can't really tell anything from those one liner screenshots. Use the inbuilt markdown to put the contents of the file.

Answer (score 4):

Environment variable in `docker-compose` are intended for the **application**. I.e. runtime environment of your application.

Dockerfile does not have environment variables. Instead - it has build arguments.

Thus, you need to use build arguments i.o. env. variables for customization of build process.

Namely:

**Dockerfile**

```
ARG ENV=prod    # default value
RUN npm run build-${ENV}
```

**Build script**

```
docker build --build-arg ENV=dev
```

or in **docker-compose**:

```
build:
    context: .
    args:
        ENV: dev
```